# Create a WiFi hotspot in Linux with Network Interface Card?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have two computers and each has an Intel AX210 WiFi network card installed.
Is there a way to connect computer 1 to a WiFi created by computer 2 (and vice versa) using Linux?

I know there is the option "Wi-Fi Settings -> Turn on Wi-Fi Hotspot" but that option is disabled in my case (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with 5.15.0.60 kernel).

I want to capture CSI data between two WiFi Links for passive detection of humans / objects.
I know that the Intel AX210 isn't supported out of the box in Ubuntu 20.04 but the software I am using (PicoScenes) backported the driver support.

Comment: Ubuntu, Settings, Network, details., Make available to other users.Does that help?

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=internet+sharing+linux